# Set the cursor on a textbox after selecting an item in a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, listbox, cursor-position

When I select an item on my Listbox, a Textbox is filled with the selected text for editing. How can I get the cursor to focus on the Textbox text so I don't have to click on it with my mouse before editing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the Control's `Focus` method:

```
TextBox1.Text = selectedItemText;    
TextBox1.Focus();
```

Or

```
TextBox1.Select();
```

Or if you just want to put a cursor after the last letter in the TextBox:

```
TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0);
TextBox1.Focus();
```